# React Native, Navigation

Tags: javascript, navigation, react-native, navigationbar

I'm kinda new in the react-native world and somehow I can't find the NavigationBar docs for react-native, is there a page,github... I could check out? It must be somewhere or how did the people know how to use it? (I'm curious).

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The React Native documentation is in general, quite poor. It is incomplete and does not cover nearly enough cases to provide valuable information. The team heavily recommends reading through the source for help.

Here is an example implementation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigationBarSample.js

Comment: I see @john-shammas, thanks, I found the stackoverflow more useful for information than actually React Native docs, I will have a look at the examples, thanks again!